# Creat matrix numbers from 1 to 64 with only one loop how can I do that?

Tags: c#

I want to create a method with signature:

```
void InitMatrixLinear(int[,] matrix)
```

but with only one loop I don't wanna create the same photo with two loops I need to make the same photo with only one loop how can I create this?

Like this I want to create:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32

33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48

49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56

57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
```

Comment: Typically, you'd use the modulo operator (`%`) to accomplish breaking it into rows.

Comment: Can you post code examples of what you tried, what worked as expected, and what wasn't working?

Comment: What has *photos* got-to-do with `int` ?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you are always creating the same matrix with values 1-64, you could use a csv file and just read it in. If you don't need each value to be specified then microsoft docs has an article explaining 2-d arrays. If you are creating a duplicate matrix, then this should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the matrix passed in is 8x8 (since we want [1,2,...,64] as the elements):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
  matrix[i%8,i/8] = i+1;
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
  matrix[i/8,i%8] = i+1;
}
```

Depending on the desired orientation of the matrix

Comment: @Mayez you express appreciation by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of the answer.